# A simple calculator using yacc

Tags: c, parsing, yacc, lexer

I need to design a simple calculator with basic operations such as +, -, /, *. At the input, the number consists of a meter, the sign | and denominator, for example 2 | 3. The number can be positive or negative. The program prints to the standard output a result in the form of a non-scalable fraction for example:
**input:**
2|1+4|1*5|2-18|5
**output:**
42 | 5

The problem is I completely don't understand yacc. In Java or C ++ I would write without any problem but I have no idea how to go about it.
I have prepared a parser and lexer and I have to use them.

**parser.y**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "parser.tab.h"

%}

digit [0-9]
digits {digit}+
plus_op "+"
minus_op "-"
mult_op "*"
div_op "/"
op_bracket "("
cl_bracket ")" 
dec_num {digits}
frac_op "|"
fraction {digits}{frac_op}{digits}

%% 

{dec_num} { yylval = strtol(yytext,NULL,10); return INTEGER; }

{fraction} { recturn FRAC; }

{plus_op} { return PLUS; }

{minus_op} { return MINUS; }

{mult_op} { return MULTI; } 

{div_op} { return DIV; }

{op_bracket} { return OTW; }

{cl_bracket} { return ZAM; }

\n { return yytext[0]; } 

%%
```

**lekser.l**

```
%{

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "parser.tab.h"

%}

digit [0-9]
digits {digit}+
plus_op "+"
minus_op "-"
mult_op "*"
div_op "/"
op_bracket "("
cl_bracket ")" 
dec_num {digits}
frac_op "|"
fraction {digits}{frac_op}{digits}

%% 

{dec_num} { yylval = strtol(yytext,NULL,10); return INTEGER; }

{fraction} { return FRAC; }

{plus_op} { return PLUS; }

{minus_op} { return MINUS; }

{mult_op} { return MULTI; } 

{div_op} { return DIV; }

{op_bracket} { return OTW; }

{cl_bracket} { return ZAM; }

\n { return yytext[0]; } 

%%
```

Comment: `I completely don't understand yacc` - then you should find a tutorial and go through that. If there's something that you can't get your head around, post a specific question about it. Asking for a complete step-by-step guide to yacc is too broad for SO.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I mean help in solving this task. I know more or less what it consists of, what are the rules, rules etc. but I don't know how to do this task. I would like to do it somehow using structures but I don't know how.

Comment: You seem to have embedded the code for/from your lexical analyzer as if it was part of your Yacc specification (`parser.y`).  It isn't — the notation for Yacc grammars is quite different from the notation for (Flex) lexical analyzers.

Comment: There are a number of completely written and well-documented examples of calculators in the [bison manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Examples). If you are new to bison/yacc, a great way to learn the basics is to study those examples and read the accompanying text. Since it is basically the same problem as you have, it will be immediately relevant as well.